# How to make correct template specialization which saves members

Tags: c++

I have an issue with specialization. I want to make a struct with specific type template specialization. But, the issue is that when I am trying to specialize the struct, then struct members are not declared.

So, I have a struct:

```
template<typename T>
struct v4
{
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            T x, y, z, w;
        };
        struct
        {
            T r, g, b, a;
        };
        T E[4];
    };

    v4() = default;

    // A lot more members, etc
    // ....
}
```

I want to specialize this structure or to get behavior I need with something like this:

```
template<>
struct v4 : v4<u16>
{
    vech4() = default;
    vech4(const v4<r32>& V)
    {
        x = EncodeHalf(V.x);
        y = EncodeHalf(V.y);
        z = EncodeHalf(V.z);
        w = EncodeHalf(V.w);
    }
};
```

How can I correctly specify template specialization and get desired behavior?

Comment: `template<>
struct v4 : v4<u16>` is not the syntax for a class template specialization. It is just invalid syntax.

Comment: And it is perfectly normal that the members from the primary template aren't there in the specialization. The whole point of declaring specializations for a class template is to make it possible to have a _different_ set of members in the specialization. This seems like a XY problem to me. What are you trying to achieve exactly? What is the behavior that you need?

Comment: Maybe look at [cppreference - Explicit (full) template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) and [cppreference - Partial template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization)

Comment: It should also be noted that it looks like you are going to be doing some type punning and while that is allowed for the structs in the union since they are standard layout and share the same common sequence, you cannot do the punning between the array and the structs.

Comment: I want to make a constructor for v4<uint16_t> in original struct. I was thinking it needed be like in the example

Comment: @ZhukovArtem When you specialize a template you tell the compiler to ignore the general template and use the specialization instead.  That means you need to put in the specialization all the members you want it to have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you specialize a template, you replace the general template definition by a new one. It looks like you want to add, not replace. If so, you should inherit, not specialize.

You should make up a new name:

```
struct v4_u16 : v4<u16>
{
    v4_u16() = default;
    v4_u16(const v4<r32>& V)
    {
        x = EncodeHalf(V.x);
        y = EncodeHalf(V.y);
        z = EncodeHalf(V.z);
        w = EncodeHalf(V.w);
    }
};
```

The new `struct` is not a template anymore, but it inherits a template instantiation and everything inside.

Comment: Using `template<>` there is a syntax error. It doesn't belong there. `v4_u16` is a non-template class.

Comment: This far I also added `using v4::v4;` and everything works great by far